# Faulty when print large number of pages in HTML PHP

Tags: php, html, css, printing, print-preview

My project required me to make a **print button** that should be able to print each personal detail in a page. I have about `1400 personal details`, and that means 1400 `pages` to print.

I am using **pagebreak** at the print page.

And I am using a **while statement** to print all the personal details, it works fine as I expected, until page `504`. So I think there's no problem with my code.

This is the example output for page 1 until 504:

[image: This is the example of output from page 1 until 504]

On the following pages, `505` and so on, the page format keeps changing for each page and I really cannot figure out why because it works well on the previous `504` pages.

[image: This is the 505th page]

Is it actually so that it cannot be printed with a large number of pages?

Any suggestions or workarounds are very appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried temporarily deleting your 504th and 505th record to see if the issue to attributed to the data or your code? I see no reason why a while loop would fail in the middle of the records. You may want to post a snippet of your looping output code to allow more feedback here..

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have tried your suggestion and the output works well (not data problem). Then I check on all of my open and close tags. I found out that one <div> element is not closed. So this settled all of this print problems.